# Use of "by themselves" and "on their own" in this context

Tags: word-in-context

Can both “by themselves” and “on their own” be used with the same meaning in this context?

> I think the better thing to do is just wait. Sometimes things can get
>   better **by themselves**.
>
> I think the better thing to do is just wait. Sometimes things can get
>   better **on their own**.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Your first sentence isn't idiomatic. Try "I think the better thing to do is just wait" or "All we can do now is wait."

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm gonna edit my question.

Comment: They both sound fine to me.